# How to find first JsonArray DTD

Tags: java

I have a question about key-value pairs in a JSON array. Let's say I want to create a dynamic code that can be used across multiple responses where I want to pick out the first JSON array, how do I go about doing that? Currently, the code below looks for a JSON array known as 'test', but the issue here is that I can only use this code for an endpoint to spits out a JSON array that has the DTD 'test'.

What I was hoping is change the line of code below so that instead of 'test' it will be 0 or first or something like that.

```
httpResponse.getBody()
    .getObject()
    .getJSONArray("test")
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .get("value")
    .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually unusual to do that. Because the first item you put into a JSON object is not the first object you retrieve, JSON library puts it in an alphabetic order.
Either way, you can use the static method of JsonObject `getNames()` and get field names and then retrieve the first name.

EDIT:
Here is an example:

```
System.out.println(new JSONObject().put("second", "goes second").put("first","goes first").toString());
```

output:

> {"first":"goes first","second":"goes second"}

And the static `JSONObject.getNames()`:

```
for(String str:JSONObject.getNames(jsOb))
{
    System.out.println("key="+str +", value="+jsOb.getString(str)); 
}
```

output:

> key=first, value=goes first
>
> key=second, value=goes second